# Why is an Application/Object error occurring for this code?

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    j = Worksheets("Graph Data").Range("C9")

    For intCounter = 0 To j
        If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Graph Data").Cells(9 + intCounter, 5).Value) = "True" Then
        With Worksheets("Graph Data")
        .Range(Cells(9 + intCounter, 3), Cells(9 + intCounter, 11)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
        .Range(Cells(9 + intCounter, 3), Cells(9 + intCounter, 11)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        .Range(Cells(9 + intCounter, 3), Cells(9 + intCounter, 11)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
        .Range(Cells(9 + intCounter, 3), Cells(9 + intCounter, 11)).Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
        End With
        End If
    Next intCounter
```

Using the exact same code, but on an ACTIVE worksheet, it works just fine. Trying to reference an inactive worksheet breaks everything. Why? How can I go about avoiding this?

All this is doing is incrementing the border around a table of data in another worksheet when a macro populates data on the current active worksheet. This functionality NEEDS to be a part of the macro that populates data on the current worksheet. It cannot be separated.

Thank you for your time.

P.S.: If you have a way of making all of these borders occur within one line of code, feel free to advise. Thank you.

Comment: `cells` within the `.range` isn't qualified, add a `.` before the `cells`

Comment: @Warcupine

Gosh. Something so simple. What a hero you are. Thank you. I have spent 30 minutes staring at this simple code, wondering why it was failing.

Thank you very much.